# Facebook unity SDK, "FB.Init() has already been called"

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am working with FB Unity SDK, and one constant problem i am facing is to check if FB.Init() has already been called.

Scenario:

1. There is a fb connect button, user clicks it.
2. If the user decides to cancel the dialog and click "Fb connect again"

FB sdk throws a notice saying "FB.Init() has already been called. You need to call this only once."

Here is what i am trying to do, but does'nt work

```
    if(FB.AccessToken=="" || FB.AccessToken==null){
        Debug.Log ("Fb not init(), call it");
        FB.Init(OnInitComplete, null);
    }else{
        Debug.Log ("Facebook already init()");
        OnInitComplete();           
    }
```

But, obviously this is not working since FB.Init() was called and the user cancelled it. How can i verify if FB.Init() has already been called? But i was expecting accessToken to be null?

And, do these messages effect the submission of the app? Will they be displayed in the production build?

Comment: btw C# string class has 'IsNullOrEmpty' to make your above checka little more efficient.

Comment: you mean FB.AccessToken.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FB.Init() shouldn't be called more than once.  This is by design (because it inits Facebook GameObjects and such within Unity).  Instead, do this:

```
FB.Init(MyOnInitComplete);

....

public void MyOnInitComplete() {
    // FB.IsLoggedIn checks for the FB.AccessToken and the FB.UserId
    if(!FB.IsLoggedIn){
        // FB.Init() is called, but user is still not logged in.
        FB.Login("<your_permissions_here>");
    } else {
        // User is logged in & FB.Init is called       
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok, did'nt know that isLoggedIn checks for a token. I will try that and post an update

Comment: That definitely helped in dealing with the issue. Thanks Brian.

Comment: @Brian Jew, can you help with that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846990/facebook-initialization-fb-sdk

Comment: This approach may be better: `if(!FB.IsInitialized) { FB.Init(...); }`