# Facebook initialization FB SDK

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using Unity and FB SDK. I'm trying to use FB.Init, but I get weird behavior, sometimes the callback from the FB.Init function is called, and sometimes it "stalls" or freezes and it never be called. How would I catch the errors from that function? Should I set-up a timeout in the initialization?

```
 public void Call(string methodName, params string[] args)
    {
        if (methodName != "init" && !Initialized)
        {
            Error("FbPluginManager not initialized.");
        }
        ReturnParams = null;
        Global.Log(LogCat.PLUGINS, "Call: " + methodName);
        switch (methodName)
        {
            case "init":
                {
                    if (args.Length != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
                    {
                        FB.Init(OnInitComplete, args[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
         }
    }
```

I have got two different Logs of the webplayer, the only difference is here:

This is a working version of the FB.Init

```
  Platform assembly: C:\Users\atolb\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Release3.x.x\Data\lib\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
    Non platform assembly: data-14D39E58 (this message is harmless)
    UnloadTime: 0.574110 ms
    System memory in use before: 47.5 MB.
    Unloading 1 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 12 / Dirty serialized files: 0)
    System memory in use after: 47.1 MB.
```

---

While a non-working, non-response from FB.Init call back doesn't have that loading that .dll.

Comment: Show the code you've used

Comment: @SahilMittal  Its a normal call to Init function of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Why do you need to do this check?

Comment: @SahilMittal I'm doing some work based on FB like getting and doing purchasing. The FB.Init should succeed.

Comment: I dont think this is really a good way to do, rather simply call your facebook apis after `init` has been initialized that's it

Comment: @SahilMittal The problem that I don't get Init or any reply from facebook sometimes. That's the original issue.

Comment: Which platform is this on?

Comment: @BrianJew That's windows 7, chrome or firefox, Unity 4.3.3F1, Facebook SDK 5.0.4, build 140220.cc3a9c089a2eb9e.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh and this is running through Facebook Canvas?

Comment: @BrianJew yes, its running through Facebook canvas.

Comment: @BrianJew Your help is really appreciated. That's a serious problem.

Comment: On canvas, FB.Init() would make a HTTP request to get the dll needed for it to load.  Is it possible that a slow internet connection is causing the hang up?  (It will also retry three times before it completely fails.)

Comment: @BrianJew Sorry for late reply, its not a slow internet, but company's internet. so maybe firewall affects that ? or Denial of service ? due to frequent testing?