# FB.Init() Issues on Facebook for Unity SDK 6.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I use the following codes to initialize Facebook SDK (in `OnGUI()`):

```
if(GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Login")) {
  if(!FB.IsInitialized) {
    FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
  } else {
    OnInitComplete();
  }
}
```

And its callback functions:

```
private void OnInitComplete() {
  Debug.Log("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
  Application.LoadLevel("NextScreen");
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown) {
  Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
}
```

Then, I run the App in a real iPhone 5s with **iOS 8.1.2**, The log shows in Xcode 6:

> FB.Init() has already been called.  You only need to call this once and only once.

```
NullReferenceException: Facebook object is not yet loaded.  Did you call FB.Init()?
  at FB.get_FacebookImpl () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FB.Init (Facebook.InitDelegate onInitComplete, System.String appId, Boolean cookie, Boolean logging, Boolean status, Boolean xfbml, Boolean frictionlessRequests, Facebook.HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity, System.String authResponse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FB.Init (Facebook.InitDelegate onInitComplete, Facebook.HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity, System.String authResponse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TitleScreen.StartGame () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TitleScreen.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename:  Line: -1)

FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? True
```

This issue does not happen in Android, or running within Unity. How can I resolve this?

p.s. This error does NOT forbid me from login to Facebook. Everything else is normal.

Referencing other similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488614/facebook-unity-sdk-fb-init-has-already-been-called) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998680/facebook-unity-sdk-login-issue)), the case is different as the version is different (the Graph API versions used are different too)

Note: Using Unity 4.6.1, Facebook SDK for Unity 6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in [this question](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/facebook-api-initialization-woes.273054/) that someone suggests not relying on FB.IsInitalized because it always returns true.

I can tell you what worked for me is to call FB.Init in the Awake() function, as done in the Facebook [Unity Games Integration Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial#authenticate_step2). I did this in a custom class I created as a singleton, so I know it is only initialized once.

```
private void Awake() {
    // Initialize FB SDK              
    enabled = false;                  
    FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);  
}

private void SetInit()                                                                       
{                                                                                            
    Util.Log("SetInit");                                                                  
    enabled = true; // "enabled" is a property inherited from MonoBehaviour                  
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)                                                                       
    {                                                                                        
        Util.Log("Already logged in");                                                    
        OnLoggedIn();                                                                        
    }                                                                                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Facebook's tutorial is outdated (it uses v5.x), maybe I should try on 6.0.0 and get back to you (p.s. I help corrected a spelling mistake)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about IOS Sdk. [See this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1381701545468646/)

So for now I think this solution works.

1-) Open your FBUnityInterface.mm with notepad or something else.

2-9) Add "self.isInitializing = NO; " to line 110 before "UnitySendMessage(g_fbObjName, "OnInitComplete", "");"